# Generic Schema in marshmallow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, marshmallow

I have a json as:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": [{
        "name": "dummy"
    }]
  }
```

I am using marshmallow to validate schema.

```
class ModelsSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(required=True)
    data = fields.???(required=True)
```

I just want to validate that the json contains the id and data fields, what is inside the data is not the concern, it could be a json or array of json or a simple string.

How can i create the schema for it using marshmallow?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with List

```
   class ModelsSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(required=True)
    data = fields.List(required=True)
```

Comment: If it is a json then use Raw() instead of List().